# Why is setState not working in React functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

```
const [bullyTypes, setBullyTypes] = React.useState([
  { value: "Exotic", isChecked: false },
  { value: "Pocket", isChecked: false },
  { value: "Classic", isChecked: false },
  { value: "Standard", isChecked: false },
  { value: "Extreme", isChecked: false },
  { value: "XL", isChecked: false },
]);

const handleBullyTypeChange = (event) => {
  let bullyTypesCopy = bullyTypes;
  bullyTypesCopy.forEach((bullyTypeCopy) => {
    if (bullyTypeCopy.value === event.target.value) {
      bullyTypeCopy.isChecked = event.target.checked;
    }
  });
  setBullyTypes(bullyTypesCopy); // not working

  setBullyTypes([
    { value: "Exotic", isChecked: true },
    { value: "Pocket", isChecked: false },
    { value: "Classic", isChecked: false },
    { value: "Standard", isChecked: false },
    { value: "Extreme", isChecked: false },
    { value: "XL", isChecked: false },
  ]); // this is working even though bullyTypesCopy variable has the same value with this array of objects.
};
```

When I pass the exact array as argument to setBullyTypes it works 
but when i pass the variable containing the array it wont work even though they have the same value

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: can you show us how you use setState, because its non in the code.

Comment: Do not mutate objects, they are compared by reference. See https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly

Comment: Hello. What i mean setState in my code is setBullyTypes. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the event handler `bullyTypesCopy` is copied by reference, and `forEach` is not doing what you expect, it just iterate over the array entries. I think what you need to do is use `map` in order to actually get a new content based on your condition. In this way `setBullyTypes` should work.

Please try the following example

```
const [bullyTypes, setBullyTypes] = React.useState([
  { value: "Exotic", isChecked: false },
  { value: "Pocket", isChecked: false },
  { value: "Classic", isChecked: false },
  { value: "Standard", isChecked: false },
  { value: "Extreme", isChecked: false },
  { value: "XL", isChecked: false },
]);

const handleBullyTypeChange = (event) => {
  let bullyTypesCopy = bullyTypes.map((bullyTypeCopy) => {
    if (bullyTypeCopy.value === event.target.value) {
      return { ...bullyTypeCopy, isChecked: !event.target.checked };
    }

    return { ...bullyTypeCopy };
  });

  setBullyTypes(bullyTypesCopy); // not working // this should work now

  setBullyTypes([
    { value: "Exotic", isChecked: true },
    { value: "Pocket", isChecked: false },
    { value: "Classic", isChecked: false },
    { value: "Standard", isChecked: false },
    { value: "Extreme", isChecked: false },
    { value: "XL", isChecked: false },
  ]); // this is working even though bullyTypesCopy variable has the same value with this array of objects.
};
```

Comment: Correct. OP thinks that `let bullyTypesCopy = bullyTypes` is creating a new object, instead that assignment is only creating a reference to the `bullyTypes` object, meaning its trying to manipulate the state value directly.

However a simpler way to copy an object can be achieved by using `Object.assign`. In this particular case `let bullyTypesCopy = Object.assign({ }, bullyTypes)` should do the trick.